# Proving $\dim(R(A)\cap R(B)) \ge \dim(R(AB))$

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ and $B$ are square matrices of order $n$.

Given $AB=BA$, prove that $\dim(R(A)\cap R(B)) \ge \text{rank}(AB)$.

Can I say that:

$\text{rank}(AB) \le \text{rank}(A) = \text{rank}(B)$

and

$\dim(R(A)\cap R(B)) \ge \dim(R(A)) = \text{rank}(A)$

Thus,
$\dim(R(A)\cap R(B)) \ge \text{rank}(AB)$?

I think there's a lot of flawed reasonings. Would appreciate it if someone can enlighten me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a good start but there are indeed a couple of flaws in your argument. Proceeding line by line:

Your first inequality, $\text{rank}(AB) \le \text{rank}(A)$ is correct since $R(AB) \subseteq R (A)$.

The equality $\text{rank}(A) = \text{rank}(B)$ does not necessarily hold. Consider, for example, what happens if $A $ is the identity matrix and $B$ is the zero matrix.

The inequality  $\dim(R(A)\cap R(B)) \ge \dim(R(A))$ is a mistake. In fact it should be $\dim(R(A)\cap R(B)) \le \dim(R(A))$ because $R(A)\cap R(B) \subseteq R(A)$.

---

One method for showing the desired inequality $\dim(R(A)\cap R(B)) \ge \dim(R(AB))$, is to show $R(A)\cap R(B) \supseteq R(AB) =R (BA)$ which follows from $R(AB) \subseteq R (A)$ and $R(B) \subseteq R (BA)$.